# How to migrate odp.net version

Tags: version-control, odp.net

I have a window form application running in client machine. some clients are still using oracle92 client and didn't install opd.net in their machine. I have updated my oracle client as 10g, and my application is currently depending on odp.net 10.1. when i deploy this application, it is not working on client's machine since they are still using oracle client 92. how can i fix this problem with change client's oracle client.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build against the ODP.NET dll from the lowest version target client. The simplest way to do this would be to install the client version they are using, making sure you install ODP.NET though, and then build against that.